# Empty data from ajax jquery when ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have code ajax like this

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async:false,
                            url: "<?php echo site_url()?>/entry/ssinv_tdi_io/insert_ssinv_ioa/",
                            data:{ DocID: DOCID,
                                   DocIDTax: iddocfull,
                                   Loop: loop,
                                   Length: result.length,
                                   IsTax:import_tax,
                                   TaxNo:taxnofull,
                                   TaxName:taxnamefull,
                                   TaxAddress:taxaddressfull
                                 }, 
                            success: function(data){
                                $("#overlay").hide();
                                $("#btnImport").prop('disabled', true);
                                if (loop == result.length-1){
                                    // alert("Import telah selesai");
                                    generate_err(DocIDFull); 
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                $("#overlay").hide();
                                alert("Error "+ jqXHR.status+' :'+errorThrown); 
                                generate_err_dev(errorThrown,jqXHR.responseText);
                                // TODO :save detail jqXHR.responseText  ke log file  untuk trace detail
                            }   
                        })
```

how to I can delete data in ajax when ajax error in event error ajax ?
Example if I remove data "DocIDTax" can I remove from set value "iddocfull" to '' but how ?

So If ajax error, it will be delete post data from ajax

here is my value "iddocfull"

```
iddocfull    = iddoc.join(",");
```

"iddoc" is array data

Thanks for helping me
Sorry if my question not important but i need help to solve this
고맙습니다

Comment: can you be more clear about what you want to do

Comment: By the way,  please do not use `async:false` - it creates a horrible user experience by locking the browser, and some browsers have deprecated it, so you can expect it to stop working in future. Instead, make your AJAX calls asynchronous in the expected way.

Comment: Anyway, what exactly do you mean "delete all data in ajax"? We're not sure what you want to do. You seem to be talking about the data you sent to the server...but that object does not really exist in the client anymore after the request is made. `iddocfull` still exists locally, but not `DocIDTax`. You want to remove some value from `iddocfull`? Please give an example so we can understand.

Comment: i has been edited my question

Comment: Sorry but that really doesn't clarify anything. Do you mean you want to delete the data from the server? Surely if the AJAX call failed it means the data was never created anyway?